# Retained fragment leak

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, loader, leakcanary

I'm using the simple activity with the retained fragment which holds some data used by the activity. The retained fragment uses the loader to get the data from a content provider. On configuration change (screen rotation) the activity is recreated and the old instance is leaked as reported by LeakCanary library (retained fragment -> loader manager -> old activity). This reproduced with the support-v4 23.0.0 library (and the previous versions also). The sample of the activity with the retained fragment where leak is reproduced (no useful code here, only to demonstrate the leak):

```
package com.leaksample;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ModelFragment mModelFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mModelFragment = (ModelFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(ModelFragment.TAG);
        if (mModelFragment == null) {
            mModelFragment = new ModelFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(mModelFragment, ModelFragment.TAG)
                    .commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

    public static class ModelFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
        private static final String TAG = ModelFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        }
    }
}
```

The stack from LeakCanary:

```
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.leaksample:1.0:1.
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * com.leaksample.MainActivity has leaked:
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * GC ROOT thread java.lang.Thread.<Java Local> (named 'Binder_1')
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.view.ViewRootImpl.mContext
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.leaksample.MainActivity.mModelFragment
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.leaksample.MainActivity$ModelFragment.mLoaderManager
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.mHost
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.this$0
08-29 19:52:34.129  15271-16632/com.leaksample D/LeakCanary﹕ * leaks com.leaksample.MainActivity instance
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong and forgot to call some `close` or `release` method? I think using the retained fragment with the loader is a common pattern and should not be memory leaks here.

Comment: Can you try creating a CursorLoader without the getActivity() call and see if there is still a memory leak?

Comment: I've replaced getActivity() with getActivity().getApplicationContext() and leak is still presents.

Comment: @user3640997 Can you show the stack from LeakCanary? It would be interesting to see the exactly leak trace.

Comment: Added LeakCanary stack to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not found the best solution other than using the next workaround. I've replaced `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` call with `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` to use activity's loader manager instead of the fragment's one. I don't know which side effects this can have but seems it works. You should make sure you don't have potential loader id conflicts if you use loaders both in the activity and fragment. Also I moved `initLoader` method call from `onCreate` to `onActivityCreated` (when called from `onCreate` the loader stopped to receive content updates after a configuration change).

Comment: does anybody know if this is fixed in current versions of support library?

Answer (score 3):

Your call to getLoaderManager() in ModelFragment ends up creating a new LoaderManagerImpl instance, which contains a reference to FragmentActivity. See below:

```
// FragmentActivity.java

LoaderManagerImpl getLoaderManager(String who, boolean started, boolean create) {
        if (mAllLoaderManagers == null) {
            mAllLoaderManagers = new SimpleArrayMap<String, LoaderManagerImpl>();
        }
        LoaderManagerImpl lm = mAllLoaderManagers.get(who);
        if (lm == null) {
            if (create) {
                lm = new LoaderManagerImpl(who, this, started);
                mAllLoaderManagers.put(who, lm);
            }
        } else {
            lm.updateActivity(this);
        }
        return lm;
    }
```

From further inspection of FragmentActivity, it appears that when the Fragment retains its instance, the loaders are not removed, and still hold a reference to the destroyed activity.

```
@Override
    public final Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        ...
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                LoaderManagerImpl lm = loaders[i];
                if (lm.mRetaining) {
                    retainLoaders = true;
                } else {
                    lm.doDestroy();
                    mAllLoaderManagers.remove(lm.mWho);
                }
            }
    ...
    }
```

One way around this would be to change the ModelFragment so that retainInstance is false.

Comment: But I need this fragment reained because in my real app it holds a bitmap which I want to keep retained across configuration changes. So, it seems it's a bug in Android?

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's a bug.